# How to display scheduled event to the clients using SignalR background continuation process?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have list of events in the database. Events have the following properties, `Message, UserId, StartDate, EndDate, StartTime, EndTime`.

My requirement is to alert the user by displaying the event before 15 minutes on the website. I am implementing this functionality by using SignalR concepts. This SignalR should process the condition in background and if it meets the condition (prior 15 minutes), it should be displayed to the respective user page automatically.

I have seen lot of SignalR examples on internet but all those examples are using a button click event or other events. In my case there is no button click events, SignalR should keep look into the database then notify Event if it meets the condition.

Please do needful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I am answering to my own question. It may helpful to others.
I have achieved this by using `Timer` class from `using System.Threading` namespace. Below is the working code for me.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;
using SignalRNotifications.Models;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Linq;
using WebMatrix.WebData;


namespace SignalRNotifications
{
[HubName("processEvents")]
public class ProcessEvents : Hub
{
    UsersContext db = new UsersContext();
    public void ShowEvent(string name)
    {
        Timer _timer = new Timer(dispmsg,                
            null,
            TimeSpan.Zero,
           TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    }
    public void dispmsg(object state)
    {

        var userEvents = db.MyEvents.ToList().Where(f => f.StartDateTime.AddMinutes(-15) >= DateTime.Now).ToList();
        Clients.All.BroadCastEvent("Hello Sridhar you have ("+userEvents.Count()+") Events<br/>");
    }

}
}
```

Simply I wrote the code in Index.html for client

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var con = $.connection.processEvents;
    con.client.broadCastEvent = function (name) {
        $("#container").append(name);

    }
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        con.server.showEvent("sridhar");
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```